# Firebase Cloud function imagemagick composite command to overlay images

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to put one image over another image using Imagemagick on cloud function and looked into the Imagemagick command like this:

> convert a.png  b.png -gravity center -composite result.png

I know it doesnt work like that in firebase cloud function, so I looked for an example and have something like this:

```
return spawn('convert', [tmpFilePath, tmpFilePath2, '-gravity', 'center', '-composite', tmpFilePath3]);
```

I get an error like this :

> ChildProcessError: `convert /tmp/default.jpg /tmp/IMG_4947.JPG
>   -gravity center -composite /tmp/newimage.jpg` failed with code 1

Comment: Can you show your function's code so we can try to reproduce? Also, how big are your pictures? Note that data written to the tmp / volume is stored in memory and will consume memory resources provisioned for the function.

Comment: Try with your images in some other directory. I do not recommend using /tmp for doing work. You could fill that directory and it will not have space for the temporary images that Imagemagick needs to utilize there.

Comment: the images are relatively smaller than 10kb. The is same as https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail i just modified it to merge two image instead of thumnail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your code and it works.

First import os and path:

```
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
```

Then you can declare the tmp paths:

```
const filename1 = 'default.jpg';
const filename2 = 'IMG_4947.JPG';
const filename3 = 'destination.jpg';

const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename1);
const tmpFilePath2 = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename2);
const tmpFilePath3 = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename3);
```

After that you can download the images using your bucket (if you don't have it you can get it from your event).

```
bucket.file(filename1).download({
            destination: tmpFilePath
        }).then(()=>{
            bucket.file(filename2).download({
                destination: tmpFilePath2
            }).then(()=>{
                return spawn('convert', [tmpFilePath, tmpFilePath2, '-gravity', 'center', '-composite', tmpFilePath3]);
            }).then(()=>{
                //Upload the image (bucket.upload(tmpFilePath3, ....)
            })
        }).catch(()=>{
            //error handling..
        });
```

It is also possible to do it in parallel instead of sequentially (Promise.all[a, b] instead of then().then()).

Comment: yes ofcourse it is check out this video by Doug
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg

Comment: How about using an URL for the images? Will it work for absolute URI of the images hosted somewhere else ?